# Error is raised when I compile simple driver module on Pi itself with a corss-compiled Kernel

Tags: kernel, cross-compilation, modules

I cross-compiled a new Kernel(3.18.10) on Debian Jessie amd64 for RPi2. Later, when I compile a simple `Hello-World` module with this kernel, however, an error is raised:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.18.10-d0u9/build M=/home/pi/Hello-World modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-source-3.18'
  CC [M]  /home/pi/Hello-World/main.o
./scripts/recordmcount: 1: ./scripts/recordmcount: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/home/pi/Hello-World/main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/pi/Hello-World/main.o] Error 2
Makefile:1398: recipe for target '_module_/home/pi/Hello-World' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/pi/Hello-World] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-source-3.18'
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

The `Hello-World` module is fairly simple:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Bye, World!\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Douglas");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Hello World program");
```

And below is the `Makefile`:

```
DEBUG = y

ifeq ($(DEBUG),y)
    DEBFLAGS = -O -g -DENABLE_DEBUG
else
    DEBFLAGS = -O2
endif

EXTRA_CFLAGS += $(DEBFLAGS)

ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    hello-world-objs := main.o
    obj-m := hello-world.o
else
    KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    PWD := $(shell pwd)

modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
endif

clean:
    rm -fr *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions
```

The directory `/lib/modules/XXXX/build` and `/lib/moduels/XXXX/source` have already linked to the source tree via `ln -s` command.

I have already compiled kernel over 3 days to solve this problem, however, nothing was obtained.

Please help me...

Comment: It looks like a cross compiling issue. Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282461/scripts-recordmcount-syntax-error-when-i-try-to-build-a-linux-kernel-module-o

Comment: I do think so, It works fine if I compile kernel on Pi itself..